# How can i create a nested json webservice in c#?

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have a list of products with product name and its group id.I need to display the same using a webservice with different levels .

i.e Level 0 should contain groupid with child level as their product names.

What i have done so far is, created two dictionaries and added rows for products and groups individually

```
 Dictionary<string, object> row1 = null; // this will have rows with groupid
 Dictionary<string, object> row2 = null; // this will have rows with prod name
```

created a var and added the values to be shown as below :

```
 var listItem = new
                {

                    ProductName = new[] {
                new  { Rack = rows1 , Item = rows2   }                                      

                    }

                };
```

And finally serialised for output :

```
this.Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { response_code = "200", listItem }));
```

My output was as below :

[image]

> But i need an output with group based,like group1 with products ,
>   group2 with products.

Like below screen :

[image]

[image]

Any help would be of great use.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you add an example of the output you want please?

Comment: let me make a dummy and add to question

Comment: @Jay let me know if further clarification on the same

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your output first you have to create two model(class) like below

```
 public class Product
 {
    public string productName { get; set; }
 }

 public class GroupModel
 {
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Item { get; set; }
 }
```

The **Product** hold product detail and **GroupModel** hold group name with a list of product. You can add other extra information in **Product** class with "productName" if need

Then you can create output from your web service like below

```
    // GET: api/Test
    public GroupModel Get()
    {
        List<Product> product = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product() {productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L"},
            new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
            new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"},
            new Product() {productName = "32"},
            new Product() {productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND"}
        };

        GroupModel listItem = new GroupModel();
        listItem.Group = "Group1";
        listItem.Item = product;

        return listItem;
    }
```

or can serialize for any purpose as like your way

```
this.Context.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(new { response_code = "200", listItem }));
```

Hope will it will help you

for group of product use like this

```
// GET: api/Test
    public IEnumerable<GroupModel> Get()
    {

        List<GroupModel> listItem = new List<GroupModel>
        {
            new GroupModel()
            {
                Group = "Group1",
                Item = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product() {productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L"},
                    new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
                    new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"},
                    new Product() {productName = "32"},
                    new Product() {productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND"}
                }
            },
            new GroupModel()
            {
                Group = "Group2",
                Item = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product() {productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L"},
                    new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
                    new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"},
                    new Product() {productName = "32"},
                    new Product() {productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND"},
                    new Product() {productName = "15 PCS WITH 16 BUNS"}
                }
            },
            new GroupModel()
            {
                Group = "Group3",
                Item = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product() {productName = "44"},
                    new Product() {productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L"},
                    new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
                    new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"},
                    new Product() {productName = "32"},
                    new Product() {productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND"}

                }
            },
            new GroupModel()
            {
                Group = "Group4",
                Item = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product() {productName = "12"},
                    new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
                    new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"},
                    new Product() {productName = "32"},
                    new Product() {productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND"}
                }
            },
            new GroupModel()
            {
                Group = "Group5",
                Item = new List<Product>
                {
                    new Product() {productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L"},
                    new Product() {productName = "Itest"},
                    new Product() {productName = "3 PCS WITH 4"}
                }
            }
        };


        return listItem;
    }
```

you can also use like this-

```
// GET: api/Test
    public IEnumerable<GroupModel> Get()
    {

        Product product1 = new Product();
        product1.productName = "12 PCS WITH 14 Buns AND 2L";

        Product product2 = new Product();
        product2.productName = "Itest";

        Product product3 = new Product();
        product3.productName = "3 PCS WITH 4";

        Product product4 = new Product();
        product4.productName = "32";

        Product product5 = new Product();
        product5.productName = "5 PCS WITH 6 BUNS AND";

        List<Product> productList1 = new List<Product>();
        productList1.Add(product1);
        productList1.Add(product2);
        productList1.Add(product3);
        productList1.Add(product4);
        productList1.Add(product5);

        List<Product> productList2 = new List<Product>();
        productList2.Add(product1);
        productList2.Add(product3);
        productList2.Add(product4);

        List<Product> productList3 = new List<Product>();
        productList3.Add(product1);
        productList3.Add(product2);
        productList3.Add(product4);
        productList3.Add(product5);

        List<Product> productList4 = new List<Product>();
        productList4.Add(product1);
        productList4.Add(product5);

        List<Product> productList5 = new List<Product>();
        productList5.Add(product4);

        GroupModel group1 = new GroupModel();
        group1.Group = "Group1";
        group1.Item = productList1;

        GroupModel group2 = new GroupModel();
        group2.Group = "Group2";
        group2.Item = productList2;

        GroupModel group3 = new GroupModel();
        group3.Group = "Group3";
        group3.Item = productList3;

        GroupModel group4 = new GroupModel();
        group4.Group = "Group4";
        group4.Item = productList4;

        GroupModel group5 = new GroupModel();
        group5.Group = "Group5";
        group5.Item = productList5;

        List<GroupModel> listItem = new List<GroupModel>();
        listItem.Add(group1);
        listItem.Add(group2);
        listItem.Add(group3);
        listItem.Add(group4);
        listItem.Add(group5);

        return listItem;
    }
```

Comment: but there are 5 groups and related products in each group !

Comment: then you can create a list of GroupModel class instead single one which will contain 5 group with different products as your need

Comment: added code for group of product, you can use like this or create individual 5 product object and add to group object

Comment: thank you for your answer ,but i think you havnt got the question clearly , i have different products in database (sql server 2008) all the products have group id ,so i need to retrieve these items and show as a nested json . i.e we cannot create static list as you have mentioned..

Comment: I have show you using static model for simplicity, but using this logic you can use database here too, for this retrieve data from database and generate list as like this using that database data, its programming logic which is in your hand